# Error inserting date and time in SQL Server 2005 datetime c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

Problem saving to SQL Server 2005:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT into survey_Request1(sur_no,sur_custname,sur_address,sur_emp,sur_date,sur_time,Sur_status)values(" + "'" + textBox9.Text + "'" + "," + "'" + textBox8.Text + "'" + "," + "'" + textBox5.Text + "'" + "," + "'" + textBox1.Text + "'" + "," + "Convert(Datetime,Convert(char(15),"+"'" + dateTimePicker2.Value +"'"+")" + "," + "'" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToLongTimeString() + "'" + "," + "'" + "Active" + "'" + ")", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I think you may need to add a little more detail than that to get an answer!

Comment: Have you heard of [little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)?

Comment: Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: Please don't build your SQL statement like that! Use [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

Comment: Never add parameters like this to a query in code. Use SqlParameters to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @user2276883 - If you want to get help here you need to provide more information, including what kind of problem you're having.  Do you get any error messages? If your result is not what you've expected, please provide both the actual and expected results.  All this information needs to be added to your original post.  If you fail to do it in a timely manner, your post will be very likely closed.

Comment: It's so harder to describe the problem ?
Seriously, you should describe it and give the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **ALWAYS** use **parametrized** queries - this prevents SQL injection attacks, is better for performance, and avoids unnecessary conversions of data to strings just to insert it into the database.

Try somethnig like this:

```
// define your INSERT query as string *WITH PARAMETERS*
string insertStmt = "INSERT into survey_Request1(sur_no, sur_custname, sur_address, sur_emp, sur_date, sur_time, Sur_status) VALUES(@Surname, @SurCustName, @SurAddress, @SurEmp, @SurDate, @SurTime, @SurStatus)";

// put your connection and command into "using" blocks
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("-your-connection-string-here-"))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertStmt, conn))
{
    // define parameters and supply values
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", textBox9.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurCustName", textBox8.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurAddress", textBox5.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurEmp", textBox1.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurDate", dateTimePicker2.Value.Date);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurTime", dateTimePicker2.Value.Time);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurStatus", "Active");

    // open connection, execute query, close connection again
    conn.Open();
    int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

It would also be advisable to **name your textboxes** with more expressive names. `textbox9` doesn't really tell me which textbox that is - `textboxSurname` would be **MUCH** better!

Comment: thank you for the advise :) i will practice this method .

Comment: im still getting the same error. Conversion Failed when converting datatime from character string.

Comment: Are you sure you copied this code correctly? Because there is no `character string` being inserted in any `datetime` field here.

Comment: @user2276883: since you didn't post any table structure, I just had to **guess** based on your code what datatypes those columns would be. You'll need to adapt as needed - I don't know what your database and code looks like - you do - so you need to change my response where required.

Comment: i copy the code :( . sorry im just a beginner in sql. The data type i used for the surdate is  datetime else is varchar .