# Storing textbox values into an SQL database using c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to store values from a group of textboxes in a tabcontrol into a datagridview which is on anothertab in the tabcontrol, however the code throws an exception with the following message "Incorrect syntax near 'System'."

this is my code that's causing the errors

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Windows_8_Login
{
    public partial class Stock : Form
    {
        public Stock()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Stock_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'loginScreenDataSet7.Stock' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.stockTableAdapter1.Fill(this.loginScreenDataSet7.Stock);


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Form dash = new DashBoard();
            dash.Show();

        }



        private void GenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random Gen = new Random();
            ProdID.Text = Convert.ToString(Gen.Next(1000000, 9000000));
        }

        private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
           {
                SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
                sc.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=LoginScreen;Integrated Security=True");
                sc.Open();
                com.Connection = sc;
                com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO Stock (Prod_ID, Prod_Name, Prod_Cat, Supplier, Cost, Price_1, Price_2, Price_3) VALUES (" + ProdID.Text + "" + ProdName.Text + "" + ProdCat.Text + "" + ProdSup.Text + "" + ProdCost.Text + "" + ProdPrice1.Text + "" + ProdPrice2 + "" + ProdPrice3.Text + "");
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sc.Close();
           }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of littl... wait isn't this almost the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062696/error-inserting-date-and-time-in-sql-server-2005-datetime-c ? Also `" + ProdPrice2 + "` is probably "System.Whatever.TextBox", when you really wanted `" + ProdPrice2.Text + "`. But PLEASE use SqlParameters!

Comment: Which line is throwing ?

Comment: use parameters http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx

Comment: Read up on how to use SQL Parameters!! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx  Also how to correctly handle SQLConnection with using()

Comment: @Corak You're brilliant man, just brilliant.  Way to catch that missing `.Text` in the comment edit window!  Couldn't you maybe let him off with some escaping just this once?  (but only if he promises to give us the exception stack-trace next time)

Comment: It would be much easier in the long-run to use the entity framework http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx

Comment: @ebyrob NEVARR! ^_^ Not using SqlParameter should be punishable by having to watch Twilight 24/7.

Answer (score 0):

Your com.CommandText contains some mistakes...
Debug it and get the value! :-)
You don't place `','` between vars and you've forgot to close the parentheses...

Like that :

```
com.CommandText = (
    "INSERT INTO Stock "
  + "(Prod_ID, Prod_Name, Prod_Cat, Supplier, Cost, Price_1, Price_2, Price_3) "
  + "VALUES ('" 
  + ProdID.Text + "','" + ProdName.Text + "','" + ProdCat.Text + "','" 
  + ProdSup.Text + "','" + ProdCost.Text + "','" + ProdPrice1.Text + "','"
  + ProdPrice2.Text + "','" + ProdPrice3.Text
  + ")");
```

However, you should use SqlParameters.  (and newlines)

Comment: Please do not tell beginners to "use SqlParameters" and then give them unsafe SQL without parameters for them to cut and paste directly in their code, because that's what they'll do.